# Scrollable HTML table with top row and left column frozen

Tags: javascript, html, scrollable-table

Has anyone been able to implement a scrollable table in HTML where the TOP row and LEFT columns are frozen, but the rest of the table is scrollable?  A perfect example of this is:
[Google Squared](http://www.google.com/squared/search?q=US%20presidents&suggest=1)

I tried to reverse engineer the code for the google squared table, but I have been unsuccessful so far.

**Note: I need the ability to FREEZE the TOP ROW and the LEFT COLUMN at the same time.**

Comment: The link is broken. Can you provide a new one, because I'm really curious what the practical value is of such a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a working example at http://ajaxian.com/archives/freeze-pane-functionality that should be easy to duplicate. Be sure to note the comments -- many of the users have made helpful suggestions for improving the script.

Per @Nirk's request, a direct link to the active demo is at http://www.disconova.com/open_source/files/freezepanes.htm.

Comment: Has anyone found a better way of doing this? I am working with some HUGE datasets and thus the tables contain a lot of data, cloning that data up to 4 times is just plain not going to work.  Does jQuery have any methods for achieving this same end?

Comment: I linked to the article intentionally -- the comments provided a lot of useful improvements that the poster should consider, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Go with a basic structure like this-

```
table
  row
    column (blank)
    column
      table (1 row high, column headers)
  row
    column 
      table (1 column wide, row headers)
    column
      div (fixed height & width, overflow auto)
        table (actual data)
```

Set a fixed table-layout and specify column widths in pixels explicitly. You should be able to achieve the same effect.

Comment: What if you want to let the the cell content determine cell dimensions (i.e. use the default table-layout)?

Answer (score 0):

i have a version of this in use (for a Gantt-chart style display).

it uses 3 tables: 1 for left column (the rows), 1 for top (columns), and then the data.

you need to work hard to get the cells to match sizes with the ones they match up to (
`table layout-fixed` can help achieve this).

The tables then are placed in some divs; the left and top divs have (as suggested above) height & width and `overflow-auto` in their css.

You then hook up some javascript to sync the scrolling of the left / top divs with the inner one...

As I recall there was a fair bit of 'curse-and-try-again', but it can be done with minimal js.

hth

Answer (score -1):

If you use jQuery there's a lot of plugins for tables with fixed head.

Answer (score -1):

You need [Scrollable](http://www.webtoolkit.info/scrollable-html-table-plugin-for-jquery.html) (jQuery plugin)

[Demo is here](http://www.webtoolkit.info/demo/jquery/scrollable/demo.html)

Comment: demo was broken in my browser (chrome)