# How to "lock" columns in an HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dhtml

I am pulling back a large amount of tabular data that I wish to display using a table.  The only caveat is that I would like to be able to "lock" a few of the columns (fname/lname/email) so that when users scroll horizontally those columns always stay "locked" in place and are visible.  I have done something similar to this before but that was back in the frameset days so that approach is no longer valid.

I was thinking about doing something clever with laying tables on top of each other but so far I have had no success with making this work.  Anyone have any clever suggestions?

A perfect example of what I am trying to do is here: 
http://www.google.com/squared/search?q=world+leaders

Comment: You could use an iframe, but IME it's a royal pain making sure the column headers are the same size as the actual data...

Comment: Found this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100835/scrollable-html-table-with-top-row-and-left-column-frozen

Comment: Ahh this is exactly what I am looking for, thank you for pointing this post out!

Comment: Unfortunately the solutions posted there aren't up to par.  The javascript that is the "accepted solution" slows to a crawl with even a small number of table rows.  I am only working with 500 and its unusable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you want, you can have a container div with position: relative, overflow: auto and fixed width. Inside of it, you separate the part you want to be locked, from the other one, into say, two different divs. The div containing the "locked" part should have position: absolute and left: 0.

It's just the big picture but you should be able to accomplish what you want this way.

Comment: I've done the same in the past by hand and its worked great  - DataTables (jQuery plugin) will do this automatically for you with this extension which makes life a bit easier! http://datatables.net/extras/fixedcolumns/

Comment: Is there a way to do this without Javascript, e.g. pure CSS?

Answer (score 0):

The code below should be pretty self-explanatory. You can add/remove rows from TBODY while THEAD remains perfectly static. This is what TBODY and THEAD exist for ;)

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
  .myTable
  {
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-spacing:0px;
    width:300px
  }

  .myTable thead td
  {
    background-color:#000;
    color:#FFF;
  }

  .myTable tbody
  {
    height:300px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
  }
</style>

<table class="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Fname</td>
      <td>Lname</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lior</td>
      <td>Cohen</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lior</td>
      <td>Cohen</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- put more rows here -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I am a little confused, how does keep things "locked" in place?  I will have several items I need in <thead> but I only want a couple of them (for the purpose of this example lets just say one of them, so first name) to stay "locked".  Real world example = http://www.google.com/squared/search?q=world+leaders -- notice how the names never move.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your problem then. I thought you meant a table with a static headers row and a scrollable body content. I will update this post tmw with a solution that covers a locked left column as well (unless you no longer require an answer since you already got one).

Comment: No actually I do still require a solution, still haven't found anything I am happy with.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

You are going to have to play with it a little so that you don't have the horizontal scroll bar as well, but you get the idea.

Of course, this didn't work in IE7. It may work in 8, but as always YMMV. Good luck. I hope this gets you started in the right direction.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var body = $('#table-body');
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
          var row = $('<tr />');
          var fname = $('<td />')
            .text('FirstName' + i);
          var lname = $('<td />')
            .text('LastName' + i);
          var email = $('<td />')
            .text('FirstLast' + i + '@example.com');
          row
            .append(fname)
            .append(lname)
            .append(email);
          body.append(row)
        }
      });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      #table-body {
        height: 150px;
        overflow: auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>Email</td>
      <thead>
      <tbody id="table-body">
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```