# sticking a certain column to right of browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, here is one for you.  I want to have a table with 4 columns total.  I only want to view 3 of these columns even when resizing my browser leaving the 4th column always hidden from view.  However, I still need to keep my scrollbar so I can scroll to the 4th column if necessary. Essentially 3 columns take 100% of viewport.

I want to use jQuery for this without any plugins.

Comment: @Fosco - You're not looking hard enough.  : )

Comment: Are all columns going to be of equal width?

Comment: @codehunter - You mean you want 3 columns in one row, then one more column in a 2nd row?

Comment: What will be contained in the 4th column? Is there no other option as to what you're going to be doing with the 4th column?

Comment: @John He wants a 4th column, off the screen, only accessible by scrolling.  Still think I'm not looking hard enough?

Comment: The widths can all be different but need to be presented in percentage so the UI is liquid.  All columns will have data that can wrap.  And I cannot split this table into two table side by side. Lets say the browser returns at 1000px wide, I want 3 columns to take 100% of that and the 4th column will remain overflowed.

Comment: @Fosco - Ok, now that the horizontal scroll has been added to the picture, it is the worst design choice I've heard as well.  : )

Comment: So far, several answers give working examples, and op keeps commenting 'doesn't work'. Time to close as 'too localized'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scrollable HTML table with top row and left column frozen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100835/scrollable-html-table-with-top-row-and-left-column-frozen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok folks.  Here's how you do it, create a function that you can call onResize in the body tag.  Create a table with a header row that colspans over 3 of the columns that will be unused, make it nowrap (important). Get the size of the total width viewport and set the first td width to that, it was actually easier than I thought:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function doColWidths(){
    $("td:first").css("width",$(window).width());
}
</script> 
</head>
<body onresize="doColWidths()">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" nowrap="nowrap"></td><td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="col1">Col1</td>
            <td id="col2">Col2</td>
            <td id="col3">Col3</td>
            <td id="col4">Col4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps someone out in the future.

Comment: Also, I forgot. Call this onload as well.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you were envisioning?  http://jsfiddle.net/daybreaker/b6LEd/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Row 1</th>
            <th>Row 2</th>
            <th>Row 3</th>
            <th>Row 4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Content</td>
            <td>Row 2 Content</td>
            <td>Row 3 Content</td>
            <td>Row 4 Content</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    width: 600px;
}

#container {
    overflow: scroll;  
    width: 600px;
}


#container table tr td {
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get this approach to work.  i like how you went with the all css route.  Good thinking but it dosen't work... :(

Answer (score 1):

JSFiddle isn't working for me at the moment, so no live demo.

*(As to why it says Rows instead of Columns, I blame @daybreaker because I started with his Fiddle)*

[image]
[image]

```
<style type="text/css">
    table { border-collapse: collapse; }
    th, td { border: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).bind('load resize', function() {
        var col_width = $('#optional-data').outerWidth();
        $('#mytable').css('position','absolute').css('right', (-1) * col_width);
    });
</script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Row 1</th>
        <th>Row 2</th>
        <th>Row 3</th>
        <th id="optional-data">Row 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1 Content</td>
        <td>Row 2 Content</td>
        <td>Row 3 Content</td>
        <td>Row 4 Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: haha. Didnt even notice I said rows instead of columns... oops. I just wanted to mess around with jsfiddle, because I just signed up for it... I agree with everyone else that this is actually a very poor design decision in the first place.

Comment: I tried this approach as well but it was unsuccessful. Thank you very much for trying though! I know it sounds like a poor design decision but it really isn't if you understood what I am actually doing with this. I think I explained that it was for an application that has OPTIONAL data in the 4th column so it isn't necessary to view it. Some clients can change the data in the 3 columns to what they want to see and optional data goes in the fourth column. It makes for less confusion on the pertinant data. I hope that explains it. Thanks for the effort! I will let you all know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Horribly bad design choice, but you'd do something like this:

1. Overall container div that takes up the whole window. height/width: 100% and scroll: none
2. Two sub-divs, one for your off-screen column, positioned absolutely within the overall div at left: 0;right:0;
3. 1st sub-div: contains your 4th column, with margin-left: 100% to push it off screen. With the no-scroll on the container div, it'll be effectively gone.
4. 2nd sub-div: contains the other 3 columns, set to width: 100% of the container div.

Of course, this begs the question: if the 4th column is permanently offscreen and therefore invisible, what is its purpose? If it's just to store other things, then you can accomplish the same thing with a hidden div. And of course, simply disabling CSS or viewing the page source would reveal the column's contents in all its glory, so it's useless for keeping secret stuff hidden.

Comment: He doesn't want it hidden, you have to be able to scroll right to see it.

Comment: I can't use divs.  Just straight HTML.  Thanks for the reply. I know you think its a horrible design choice but its for an application that has lots of data, the 4th column is optional data. So there is the reason for the "Horrible design choice" as you state

Comment: Is it an actual table? If that's the case, then you can use jquery to set the width of the 3 columns to take up the viewport's width, and the 4th column to be off-screen.

Comment: Yes, I am still working on the jQuery approach.  What I wish jQuery had was a way to position the right side of a cell to 100% of the browser window and everything else falls into place without having to figure out all the other cells widths and assign percentages to them. I would still like this liquid so when you resize it the 3 columns stay 100% and the 4th column remains overflowed.

Comment: There is an onresize event of some sort, which detects resizing the browser window. Never used it myself, but you could probably trap that even to recalculate the column widths.