# Table thead and first tbody column stays fixed in scrollable div

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table

I'm trying to make `fixed` `table` fields in scrollable `div`.

**HTML part:**

```
<div class="scroll">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Title #1</td>
                <td class="second">Title #2</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Name #1</td>
                <td>Description</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name #2</td>
                <td>Description</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS part:**

```
table {

    width: auto;
}

table > thead > tr > td {

    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;

    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid #666666;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

table > thead > tr > td.second {

    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;
}

table > tbody > tr > td {

    padding: 30px 0;
}

div.scroll {

    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Where `div.scroll` have `max-height` and `max-width` set to lower sizes than `table`. Please see [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hmvxf/).

**Live example:**
[image: example]

Red part should stay at `top` when scrolling vertically, but should move when scrolling horizontally, and blue part should move when scrolling vertically, but should stay at `left` when scrolling horizontally.

**Question:**

Is there any easy way of doing this? Or what is best way of doing this..?

Comment: try this : http://fixedheadertable.com/

Comment: Check the below.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100835/scrollable-html-table-with-top-row-and-left-column-frozen

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684211/html-table-with-fixed-headers-and-a-fixed-column

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114417/fixed-left-column-and-header-in-html-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jQuery` solution for my problem: [STICKY TABLE HEADERS & COLUMNS](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/01/09/sticky-table-headers-columns/).

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hmvxf/1/
please check this update of your code

Made a few changes

```
<div class="fixed">
     <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Title #1
                </td>
                <td class="second">
                    Title #2
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not really what I was looking for. This won't work with wide tables.